# Get typed object keys in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this situation:

```
const data: Record<string, string> = {
    a: '110px',
    b: '160px',
};

interface Props {
    d?: keyof typeof data[];
}

const t = (d: Props) => 'hi' + d;

t(['a']) // here should be allowed only data keys (a and b)
```

I want to restrict the `t()` arguments only to `data` object keys. I tried as above but I get TS error:

> Type 'string[]' has no properties in common with type 'Props'.(2559)

How to achieve this?

**NOTE**: I need to do this dynamically reading the keys of the object.

Demo: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDASgU1AJzgHmhwEswBzAGhiNLID4YBeGAbwCgZOZUYByARn4AGAA4APXhQ5cARmgEA2URKkBfANxstpKJhwAzBMEwwACjhAiIraZzgB%20NAGtMATxD6YUVyMwf4SAgA2gC6mqpabKCQsLDMABRwaOaWEACUTAy8ABbEvDAA1PCabFDxQbwIvCEZAPS1MNl6JhDZIACuADZwMDImCJ2dIADumD3gna4ByDAurtbxCNxgPTJpQA)

Comment: Not possible without sacrificing `keyof` or the index signature.

Comment: @caTS, so why my example is not working?

Comment: *"i need to do this dynamycly reading the keys of the object"* Define "dynamically." Do you mean "handles it if I change the code defining `data`" (possible) or "handles it at runtime" (not possible with TypeScript, which is compile-time only).

Comment: @Asking You defined the props wrong. It should be `({ d }: Props) =>`.

Comment: What is `Props` doing / for? You seem to be passing an array of keys, but `Props` defines a non-array object type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i need to restrict the function argument to `data` object keys.

Comment: @Asking - That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, with `keyof typeof data[]` i want to restrict the argument function to [a], [b], [a,b]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two answers for you:

1. If by "dynamically" you mean **at runtime**, no, that's not possible with TypeScript. TypeScript only works with compile-time information.
2. If by "dynamically" you mean it works even if you change the object literal that creates `data`, you can do it with `(keyof typeof data)[]` and allowing TypeScript to infer the type of `data` (by removing the type annotation on it):

   ```typescript
   const data = { // <== Note no `Record<string, string>` on this
       a: '110px',
       b: '160px',
   };

   const t = (d: (keyof typeof data)[]) => 'hi' + d;
   t(["a", "b"]); // <=== Works as expected
   t(["x"]); // <=== Error as desired
   ```

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvGB6bMA8q6AciFAKYxggwAGASuaAE5z7TMCWYA5gDQwO3HgD5aMcDCgALThABQMJTAQAuGAHIAjFoAMABwAeGvouUAjddoBsB46YC+AbnnzQkWLHQAKOOu8A1uQAniAAZlLB+uTh8EgIAJQA2gC6CWgimrIaMADU8C7yUN5JAEQIpQKl5qVpTjh4hEQwAOogzAEQKl3khtHAFHBFJaWGtQn1uARE6ACizMzt3fDkEJzM5HBAA)

   If you change the object literal defining `data` so that it (now) has a `c` property, the definition of `t` doesn't have to change ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvGB6bMA8q6AciFAKYxggwAGASuaAE5z7TMCWYA5gDQwO3HgD5aMcDCgALThABQMJTAQAuGAHIAjFoAMABwAeGvouUAjddoBsB46eUxgVrQA47J+QF8A3PPmgkLCw6AAUcOqhANbkAJ4gAGZSsfrkifBICACUANoAulloIpqyGjAA1PB+8lChOQBECPUC9eb1BT44eIREMADqIMxRECoj5IapwBRwNXX1wO1ZnbgEROgDQyMIYxNM07MNhovL3WswAKLMzIOj8OQQnMzkcEA)), it picks that up.

   As [captain-yossarian from Ukraine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian-from-ukraine) pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909272/get-typed-object-keys-in-typescript/73909374?noredirect=1#comment130502424_73909374), starting with TypeScript 4.9, if you want to make sure that you can't accidentally add an entry to `data` that doesn't have a string value (or even a more specific one, more in a minute), you can use the new [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton) operator. That lets you enforce a limitation on the object's properties **without** broadening its type, like this:

   ```typescript
   const data = {
       a: '110px',
       b: '160px',
   } satisfies Record<string, string>;
   //^^^^^^^^^−−−−−− new TypeScript 4.9 operator

   const t = (d: (keyof typeof data)[]) => 'hi' + d;
   t(["a", "b"]); // <=== Works as expected
   t(["x"]); // <=== Error as desired
   ```

   When you do that, if you try to add `c: 42` to `data`, you'll get an error from TypeScript ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDXMEBcMA5AIykAMADgB7EA0OeARkWQGzV2N4zBEAWAEwwA9KJgAeVDJgBRAE4KQC+jABuCADYBXAKYwAlhDDFYKaAsNgA5lgC+MCEmMAzQ3ogwASntAK4SUtrGzVg2wA+AG4sLFBIWFh0AAo4ImSAaz0ATxBXGChsqj08+CQEAEoAbQBdCrQIkgALQ2IYAGp4GKwoZKqAIgR+tX7mfrqosQlpWQB1FQyvBC89GmLgKD04Hr7+mnGKyfEpGXRFZQV8LzhPQwUtoA)) because that would mean that `data`'s type didn't satisfy the constraint `Record<string, string>`. But unlike `as`, it **won't** narrow the type of `data`, so our `keyof typeof data` still sees only `data`'s actual property names as a union (`"a" | "b"`), not just `string`.

   As he also pointed out, if you want to make sure all of your values in `data` are in the form `<number>px`, you can use a template literal type like `` Record<string, `${number}px`> `` with `satisfies` ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDXMEBcMA5AIykAMADgB7EA0OeARkWQGzV2N4zBvQATgEswAcxjMArrDAhYUABYBTGCLGLYAMxCCAtkmIwA9MZgAeVFZgBRQYN30YANwQAbKauEQwxWCiFRMSwAXxgIJG8tYWUIGAAlZVBBOHNA8ScAAwASDDApPWZlQRDaTIA+AG4sLFBIWERkACY0TCZcQhJyLgZ2yTZSTlpe3n4ugA4ekzNLa3jhDW1dAyhQ8MiIaNiEpN1U9LEs3PzC4tKaCuqgA)).

Comment: That said, if #2 is the answer, I'm sure there's a previous question we should point this question at...

Comment: Btw, if you still want to make sure that `data` should be assignable to `Record<string, string>` you can use `satisfies`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/NdYLXm). Also, since values are `${number}px`, we can make Record type more safer: `Record<string, `${number}px`>`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - It already satisfies `Record<string, string>`, doesn't it? At least, I can assign to one. (But not, oddly, ```Record<string, `${number}px`>```.) https://tsplay.dev/N7ypDW I can't wait to play with `satisfies`, seems like a great addition.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - (FYI: The trick to having backticks in comment code is using three backticks at the beginning and end of it instead of just one.)

Comment: Yes, it satisfies, but when you use `satisfies` you will provide an extra restriction for `data` object. For instance, you can add another one key/value pair : `c:42` and you will not get an error (without `satisfies`)

Comment: Left an example with comments [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nr4alW)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - Ah, I see what you mean, I just didn't get your point at first. Also: How did I miss that "Nightly" option on the drop-down?!